# Cool air on sweat

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water

When my face is full of sweat, I go near the A.C. and when the cool air touches my sweat it feels colder than dry parts? Why does the sweat feel colder than dry parts?

Comment: Because it evaporates and removes heat from your body.

Comment: Sweat is supposed to cool you down and has been evolutionarily ‘designed’ and kept that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [heat of evaporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization) of the water is $\pu{2260J/g}$. That means for every one gram of water, it takes $\pu{2260J}$ of energy to vaporize it. The water (evaporating) takes the needed heat energy from your $\pu{37 ^\circ C}$ body.

[Source](http://www.kentchemistry.com/links/Energy/HeatVaporization.htm)

Comment: And OP would feel the same effect if they used plain tap water instead of sweat.

Comment: @Jan Sorry but what does OP mean?

Comment: But then I should feel the same when near a fan, but A.C. seems to be much cooler. Why?

Comment: @RamKeswani OP is original poster; in this case the person who asked the question (you). And you do feel the same effect near a fan. The aircon is colder because it is blowing cool air at you rather than ambient air.